# Is there an alternate version of "Duel" where the truck stands waiting for the guy after the train has passed by?

Tags: alternate-version, duel

Every time I watch the movie "Duel" (1971), I think the exact same thing in the train scene: that, after the train has passed by and he is so relieved, the truck will stand right there, menacingly waiting for him, shocking and scaring him.

But it never happens. Yet I seem to have this memory. It just *feels* like it *should* happen. I very strongly expect it to.

Is it possible that I saw some sort of "alternative version" where this does indeed happen? If I were a film director, I would create two slightly different versions of my movie just to make it genuinely interesting to re-watch it, as you never know if some things will be different. It seems plausible that others would have this idea as well.

Comment: There is no indication of an alternate version anywhere, just an "extended" version. This sounds likes "in my head fan fiction".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the train scene was added for the theatrical release. As far as I know there are only the two versions of the film, so if the train crossing is in the version you watched then that's the only way the scene plays out; it's not in the other version at all.